# Do a Unit test with an H2 database

Tags: java, spring, junit, h2, junit4

I am starting to write some Unit test with an H2 database.

Therefore, I want to create a table out of my @Entity.

However, I always get the following error message:

> 12:40:13.635 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in at.wrk.fmd.config.JpaConfigTest: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
>
> Table "ROLLETEST" not found; SQL statement:
>
> INSERT INTO RolleTest(created_at, bezeichnung) VALUES (now(), 'ADMIN') [42102-197]
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Here are my classes:

JpaConfigTest

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource("application.propertiesTest")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
     
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "sa", null);
        new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("/import-test.sql")).execute(dataSource);
 
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

InMemoryDbTest:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
  classes = { JpaConfigTest.class }, 
  loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional
@WebMvcTest
public class InMemoryDbTest {
     
    @Resource
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
     
    @Test
    public void givenStudent_whenSave_thenGetOk() {
        Student student = new Student(1, "john");
        studentRepository.save(student);
         
        List<Student> student2 = studentRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

application.propertiesTest

```
server.port=8080
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

# H2
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

import-test.sql

```sql
INSERT INTO RolleTest(created_at, bezeichnung) VALUES (now(), 'ADMIN');
```

Maybe someone can tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: Looks to me like the error message is telling you there is no table named `ROLLETEST` (case is ignored), yet you try to insert into it. Have you created the table?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, for answering so late, but I have been ill the last couple of days.
What I did wrong was that I was not aware of doing an Integration test here.
So, some steps had to be done before doing the test itself.
I copied the application-test.properties to besides my application.properties file.
Then I annotated my main test class as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Then ApplicationContext starts up, creates my tables in my in-memory-database and I can do my tests.